# Indicator function for normed vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Recently I came across the following question:
Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces and $T: X \to Y$ be a continuous linear map. Is there always a linear functional $\xi \in Y^*$ such that $\ker(\xi) = \overline{\text{im}(T)}$?

Or more generally: Given a closed linear subspace $H \subseteq X$, is there always such a linear functional?

I thought about it a lot, but the only idea I had is the following:
Assume the existence of a linear functional $\xi \in X^*$ such that $\ker(\xi) = \{0\}$ (I honestly do not think that such an $\xi$ always exists), then we can just set $\xi(h) = 0 \; \forall h \in H$ (This is (probably) fine for linearity, but what about continuity? Maybe the closedness of $H$ saves this argument).

Thanks for help!

Comment: The kernels of linear functionals have co-dimension $1$ (except for the zero functional). The only statement of this form you can make is that for $H\subset X$ closed and not al of $X$ there is a linear functional $\xi$ with $\ker(\xi)\supseteq X$.

Comment: This is not true even of finite dimensional spaces. For example, $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, then no row vector $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$ has kernel exactly $(1,0,0)$.